# Configure .ccls file for Vim

Tags: c++, vim, compiler-errors, linker

I have no idea what I am doing. I decided to use Vim as my only editor, I'm trying to set up autocompletion and syntax checking.

So I need to configure a `.ccls` file in the root of my project (and I don't want to generate a `compile_commands.json` file so please don't tell me about it). But there is no detailed documentation whatsoever on `.ccls` because all it does is use compiler flags, which of course I don't know; I have started not too long ago in C++ and I don't know any CMake, I was used to just run my code from the IDE!

I know that the default code to put in my `.ccls` is the path to my includes, which I do put (which are 5 paths that I get using `clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null`) and I'm on mac btw. I put these, I get autocompletion, but my source breaks with errors telling things like iostream and every other header does not exist in `/usr/local/include` even though I provided 4 other paths (it really doesn't exit in `/usr/local/include` I don't know where iostream and those others are) and that I can't `cout << "Hello, World!" << endl` for example because ostream and `char[]` are incompatible and things like that. BTW even if I use `compile_commands.json` I still get errors it only fixes my header paths.

Can someone just explain how to use `.ccls`? No links, just plain explanation. Or at least a default configuration to get me going.

P.S Do I also need to provide paths to my project's header files?

This is my `.ccls`:

```
clang++
%cxx -std=c++17
%cxx -stdlib=libc++
%hxx --include=Global.h
%cxx -I/usr/local/include
%cxx -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
%cxx -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
%cxx -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
%cxx -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
```

Comment: What are the paths that `clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null` returns?

Comment: /usr/local/include - 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1 - 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include - 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include - 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include

Comment: I don't think this matters, for example, why does ccls tell me that ostream and char[] are incompatible? I think it's because it needs the template implementation but can't find it. Still, I can't fix anything. Starting to consider switching to VSCode.

Comment: `iostream` should be under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1` If you add `-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1` (don't forget the `-I`) to your `.ccls` file, it should be able to found headers from the standard library. The other directories will be required for other header files.

Comment: After rereading your question and comments, I wonder if the C++ file is correct. Does it compile? The fact that it finds `ostream` and `char[]` to be incompatible is indeed strange.

Comment: Regarding the configuration, mine is little bit complex. I don't use a `.ccls` file but instead I fill in the compiler settings to `ccls` through `coc.nvim` API. I'm not sure it will help you. And as you guessed, the `compile_commands.json` file will just inject the paths from your project, not the paths related to your installation of clang/libc++.

Comment: @LucHermitte Thanks for your help! My code compiles just fine. It's just the configuration that is not right, wether it's .ccls or compile_commands.json. I have indeed tried what you've told me, but I'll just keep trying again.  But what's your coc.nvim configuration I didn't understand what you meant by it. Does it substitute creating a .ccls file every time you start a new project? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @LucHermitte I think I might have figured something out; It's only searching the first path. For example, if I put the path where <iostream> is, then I no longer get an error about finding it, but start getting errors about other libraries that they do not exist. Do you know how I would be able to resolve this? maybe create a symlink to include all of them in one place?

Comment: _"what's your coc.nvim configuration"_ I don't use ccls directly but through [COC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/). Also, I don't use any `.ccls` file but instead I automatically configure ccls on the fly with the right parameters for each possible machine where I use vim(+coc+ccls). I've a very [short description](https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/gaelt3/dont_use_vim_for_the_wrong_reasons_by_romainl/fp009up/) of how I work on reddit. Note that not only it requires COC but also my (huge) C++ plugin that is used to do some mumbo-jumbo to fetch `clang++ -E -x c++ - -v</dev/null`

Comment: Regarding your other question, I wouldn't define any symlink. I'm curious about the content of your `.ccls` file. Is it correctly defined? It should (according to what I found online) start with clang++ then contain all the paths (returned by clang) prefixed either with `-isystem` or with `-I`, I don't remember. You should edit your question to complete it with your `.ccls` file.

Comment: @LucHermitte I have added my configuration. Please note that I tried all sorts of combinations like replacing %cxx with %cpp (I use cxx extensions), removing %cpp completely, adding just one path rather than 4, and all kinds of stuff you can try with those paths.

Comment: @LucHermitte do you mean your lh-... plugin on github? I saw many people recommend it, but I don't want to install it, at least not yet, because it seems too complex for now.

Comment: @LucHermitte I just checked out your reddit response; I indeed tried doing so a few hours ago, it was recommended by the creator of .ccls, but it only included 2 paths out of 5, and although I did not get any "library not found error", I did get the "ostream and char[]" not compatible.

Answer (score 6):

I may be wrong, but I would keep it simple and simply put these lines in the `.ccls` file

```
clang
-std=c++17
-stdlib=libc++
-isystem/usr/local/include
-isystem/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
-isystem/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
-isystem/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
-isystem/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
```

If it works with this at first, then you could prefix all these lines with `%cxx %c` -- well, `-std=c++17`, `-stdlib=libc++` and `..../include/c++/v1` are just for C++ though.

BTW, I'm not sure if the first line shall be `clang` or `clang++`.

Note: I've used `-isystem` because of the following:

> You can use -I to override a system header file, substituting your own version, since these directories are searched before the standard system header file directories. **However, you should not use this option to add directories that contain vendor-supplied system header files; use -isystem for that.**  -- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: Thanks for the time you put in to help! Unfortunately it is still not working. Your implementation is probably the right one, but I guess it's something from my setup. I downloading libc++ and storing it somewhere organized on my computer, I'll leave Clang running on Apple's Developer Tools Clang though, I'll only use this build as a path for my .ccls. I'm guessing this must work, because there's really no other reason why it shouldn't. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Last shout for help; how would I go about getting compile_commands.json to work? It seems to get all the heavy lifting done, but I'm still get petty errors like the "ostream incompatible with char[]" error. I'm generating the compile_commands.json file with "cmake -H. -BDebug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES" and my CMakeLists.txt file just contains the standard data with the executable. I've been a huge pain but thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: Unless the packing is done _strangely_ you should already have libc++, it the one in `include/c++/v1`. Now... I'm not using Macs, and I hope I'm not wasting your time. Regarding `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON`, it's required once, then it'll appear in the compilation directory. The easy approach is to have a symlink on this file in the source directory. You may have to replace `clang` with `%compile_command` IIRC.

Comment: Now, there is something that have been bugging me from the start. Why is you error message about `ostream` instead of `std::ostream`? Is it because ccls simplifies messages? Or have you committed the beginner's sin of having a `using namespace std;` in a header file? As you were working so far without any `-Iproject/paths` it really could explain what you're observing.

Comment: Honestly I'm the one wasting your time I should be thanking you. No I'm indeed NOT "using namespace std". Made sure not to get used to it. It's been bugging me as well. I can "std::cout" decimals fine, but I can't print anything else. And I can't use "std::endl" as well, it asks me if I mean't to use an implementation of it. It's like it's using specified implementations rather than templates, I get these errors usually when I'm working with templates and not including the implementation as in the ".cxx" file

Comment: And you said to replace clang with %compile_command; do you mean I should include a .ccls file as well as a compile_commands.json file at the same time? Anyways, I don't want to waste your time anymore; you've been using Vim for a long time, and I don't want to leave Vim just because of some silly thing like this, can you provide me with an alternative that is much simpler? is YouCompleteMe a good "Smart" alternative for example? Integrates well with things like Ale and Airline? If you can't continue with the conversation I can just switch to VS Code no hard feelings. Thanks!

Comment: GOOD NEWS: I have deleted coc.vim and installed YouCompleteMe; I set up very basic settings and it is working great so far, except it does not have the level of completion the coc has, but I think it can configured to act like so. Sorry I waisted so much of your time :/ It's a little weird using it but I guess I'll just get used to it.

Comment: Don't worry about my time. I'm actually interested to know about mac system because I'm not sure my plugin that use libclang would correctly work on this system. It's nice you've found a solution with YCM. If I knew you were using COC, I've have suggested you to use the 20ish lines of configuration I have in my .vimrc (but with the actual paths for your system instead of my call to `map(copy(lh#cpp#tags#compiler_includes('clang++')), '"-isystem".v:val')`)

Comment: Yes well I did install your plugin after I installed YCM, but it kind of broke; YCM wasn't completing everything anymore (things like preprocessor keywords or the namespace of a program). However, YCM is a little too bad compared to COC, it really is not that smart in completion and everything it completes is an ID rather than a language keyword, no explanation or documentation (at least I haven't figured it out yet) etc.. So I'm going to re-download COC and fix that problem once and for all. I've also just downloaded VS Code and trust me this Vim is priceless you can't leave once u learn it.